# Get last changed value with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I got few selects. How can I get the value of the last changed element? For example I select option with value 5 and i want to alert(5); Then I select option 7 and i want to alert its value.

```
<form>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option> 
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var lastSelected;   // Store the last selected option

$("select").on("change", function(){
  lastSelected = this.value;
  alert(lastSelected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option> 
    </select>
</form>
```

Clearly, if you don't need to store the value into a variable you could simply do:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
  alert( this.value );
});
```